# R group by and encode top 5 occurring rows

Tags: r, dplyr

I have the following dataframe:

```
ID | Item |
1  |  A   |
1  |  A   |
1  |  A   |
1  |  B   |
2  |  B   |
2  |  B   |
1  |  B   |
1  |  C   |
2  |  A   |
2  |  A   |
3  |  C   |
3  |  B   |
3  |  C   |
3  |  B   |
3  |  A   |
2  |  C   |
```

I would like to take the Top 2 most popular/occurring item of each ID and encode them. Desired result is:

```
ID | Item A | Item B | Item C |
1  |   1    |   1    |   0    |
2  |   1    |   1    |   0    |
3  |   0    |   1    |   1    |
```

As long as the item is in the Top 2 of an ID, it will get a count of 1.
How can I go about in R? I'm thinking of group_by %>% top_n(n=2)...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is one idea. One thing to think about is what do you want to do if there are ties? Here I sort the columns and then `slice` for the first two. You may come up with another way to deal with ties.

```
library(tidyverse)

dat2 <- dat %>%
  count(ID, Item) %>%
  arrange(ID, desc(n), Item) %>%
  group_by(ID) %>%
  slice(1:2) %>%
  mutate(n = 1) %>%
  pivot_wider(names_from = Item, values_from = n, values_fill = list(n = 0)) %>%
  ungroup()
dat2
# # A tibble: 3 x 4
#   ID     A     B     C
#   <int> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
# 1     1     1     1     0
# 2     2     1     1     0
# 3     3     0     1     1
```

**DATA**

```
dat <- read.table(text = "ID Item
1  A
1  A
1  A
1  B
2  B
2  B
1  B
1  C
2  A
2  A
3  C
3  B
3  C
3  B
3  A
2  C",
                  header = TRUE, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
```

Answer (score 2):

```
library(tidyverse)

df %>%
  group_by(ID) %>% 
  count(Item) %>% 
  top_n(2, n) %>%
  ungroup() %>%
  pivot_wider(names_from = Item, values_from = n,
              values_fn = list(n = ~ 1),
              values_fill = list(n = 0))

# # A tibble: 3 x 4
#      ID     A     B     C
#   <int> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
# 1     1     1     1     0
# 2     2     1     1     0
# 3     3     0     1     1
```

**Description**

- `values_fn = list(n = ~ 1)`: convert count numbers to 1
  ( It's equivalent to add `mutate(n = 1)` before `pivot_wider`)
- `values_fill = list(n = 0)`: specify 0 to be filled when missing

Comment: I like your answer Darren, but doing it on a huge dataset, I encountered ties which www's method had addressed, hence I gave it to www. Thanks alot for your effort!